# How can I merge Stack Overflow account with my openID account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I have an account in Stack Overflow ,later I came to know that we can use openid for all stack  websites so I created one.
But now I want my original ID merged in this account.

Comment: @Bobby I have flagged my question and waiting for moderator to update
Thanks

Comment: will i loose reputaion and badges that I earned at in [Stack Overflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1101032/livinggourmand)?